# Jupyter Book, how to change font or spacing (text formatting)

Tags: python, pdf, text, formatting, jupyter

Is there any way to configure how the final HTML and PDF output via LaTeX will look like? I want to for example change the line spacing.
Haven't been able to figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://ipypublish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This is the ipypublish page, I am using Jupyter Book. https://jupyterbook.org/